# Check the correlation of two columns in a dataframe (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I want to check the Correlation between two columns (c1 and c2) in my Dataframe (df)

```
cor(df$c1, df$c2, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
```

But as an output I just get "NA"

Comment: you need to pick a method dont you? not list all of them? also it is hard to help without a sample of your data. please include a reprducible example

Answer (score 0):

Your call of `cor` appears to be correct.

It works well for me using the minimal example below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  c2 = c(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10)
)

cor(df$c1, df$c2, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
```

which gives you the wanted output: `[1] 0.9918652`

I suspect your `df` data frame includes some `NA` values.
If any `NA` exists in your `df` then output of the `cor` call would indeed be `NA`.

Try call `cor` with `use` parameter set to `na.or.complete` instead. Like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  c2 = c(0, NA, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10)
)
cor(df$c1, df$c2, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"), use = "na.or.complete")
```

This way you do not have to worry about `NAs`anymore. The correlation output will be given, just skipping all `NA` in the input structure.

Comment: Hello, you are right! There was an error coming from my data frame. Thank you!

Comment: I just added another point in my answer: you may want to always call ```cor``` with ```use = "na.or.complete"``` to handle the ```NAs```

Answer (score 0):

You get this result because one of your columns has an `NA` value in it. To deal with the `NA` values, set the `use` parameter.

From the documentation for `cor()`

> use
> covariances in the presence of missing values. This must be (an
> abbreviation of) one of the strings "everything", "all.obs",
> "complete.obs", "na.or.complete", or "pairwise.complete.obs".an optional character string giving a method for computing

The `use` argument defaults to `everything`, which produces an `NA` result if there are `NA` values. Set `use` to `complete.obs` to only use the non-`NA` values.

```
cor(df$c1, df$c2, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"), 
    use = "complete.obs")
```